# HttpURLConnection and download large files

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I use `HttpURLConnection` to download files from a url.

```
 URL obj = new URL(url);
 HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

 // optional default is GET
 con.setRequestMethod("GET");
 con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

 int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

 System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
 System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

 try {
     InputStream inputStream = con.getInputStream();
     FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\programs\\TRYFILE.csv");

     int bytesRead = -1;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

     while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     }

 } catch(Exception e) {

 } finally {
       outputStream.close(); 
       inputStream.close();
 }
```

The code works to download small sized files (i.e. 25 KB). I didn't try to download large files (on the order of 100 MB), because the files from the particular URL are always small.

I want to know what happens if I try to download larger files with this code: will it continue to work or throw an exception? Do I need to implement code (utilizing, say, `setConnectTimeout` or `setReadTimeout`) for bigger files?

Is there a url you can suggest where I can try to download large file using this code?

Comment: I suggest that you start with running this code on large files and see if you're running into issues (and if so, which issues), before you're trying to solve them.

Comment: Can you suggest url which include large text or csv files ?Because I can't try with my URL?My URL gives always small files.

Comment: Generate a large file, put it in a reachable location on your server and use a URL that points to that file. Shouldn't be difficult. Remember to run this experiment many times (in a loop) in order to increase the chances of running into a (possible) issue.

Comment: Your main thread will get locked until the download is finished. So, if you want to keep your program active you should do that task in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, create a large file yourself. To serve it over HTTP, the easiest way is probably to run Python 3 from the directory where you put the file -

```
python -m http.server
```

which will start a server on 8000. See [this blog post](http://blog.abahgat.com/2011/12/13/http-server/) for more details, or check out the python documentation.

Then you can test this yourself.